# Exception not showing list values

Tags: c#, list, exception, ienumerable

In my Exception class, I pass an IEnumerable of IpAddresses. When the exception is thrown, this is what I see.

[image]

How come it doesn't give me an option to see the values inside my IEnumerable?

Here's the code that's causing the problem:

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public List<string> IpAddresses { get; private set; }


    public CustomException(string message, IEnumerable<string> ipAddresses)
        : base(message)
    {
        IpAddresses = ipAddresses;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exception? it sounds like its receiving an empty IP

Comment: Can you post the code that's throwing the exception? Kind of hard to figure much out with this little info.

Comment: can you post some code showing the surrounding code and the line that errors?

Comment: @SpaceSteak I've edited my post.

Comment: @CodingMadeEasy I answered, assuming you already used the Exception.Data Property. Maybe you could try to use it. :)

Comment: @BugFinder I've edited my post.

Comment: @PhilippPickartz I'll take a look.

Comment: You can't assign `IEnumerable<string>` to `List<string>` so the code is suspicious. What are you actually doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem! It was something I completely glossed over. The exception was being caught as a general Exception

```
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

So since it was being cast to a general exception, the value wasn't being displayed.

Comment: It's obvious, you could not see the list values. But I wonder, why you cuold see the List<string> while debugging...

Comment: @PhilippPickartz Yeah I know. I feel borderline stupid for missing something so obvious. My excuse is that I haven't had my coffee yet :p. Also yes, I find that really strange. If it is cast, it shouldn't show the value at all. Oh well, that's Microsoft's problem not mine (I hope). Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I wondered, why you can see the empty Property of your derived Exception class. Look here for [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921347/why-do-you-see-the-empty-property-of-an-derived-exception-while-debugging-and/31921799#31921799).

Comment: @PhilippPickartz Awesome thanks! We both learned something :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a key conflict in the `Exception.Data` Dictionary:

> Avoid key conflicts by adopting a naming convention to generate unique keys for key/value pairs. For example, a naming convention might yield a key that consists of the period-delimited name of your application, the method that provides supplementary information for the pair, and a unique identifier.
>
> Suppose two applications, named Products and Suppliers, each has a method named Sales. The Sales method in the Products application provides the identification number (the stock keeping unit or SKU) of a product. The Sales method in the Suppliers application provides the identification number, or SID, of a supplier. Consequently, the naming convention for this example yields the keys, "Products.Sales.SKU" and "Suppliers.Sales.SID".

Mybe the [microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) could help you out.