# Why do you see the (empty) Property of an derived Exception while debugging and catching it as Exception?

Tags: c#

While reading and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920078/exception-not-showing-list-values) question and answer here on Stackoverflow I wondered, why you can see the `List<string>` but are not able to access it.

In my understanding, you can not access the members of a derived class within the base class. Then, why does it happen to be this way?
Apparently you can see it, but you can't do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger has information about the actual runtime type stored in the variable - that's part of the runtime metadata in .NET.

This means that it can actually show you *exactly* what you're looking at, while the only thing the compiler can work with is the *compile*-time type - in other words, the one you explicitly (e.g. `Exception`) or implicitly (`var`) specify.

You can replicate the same behaviour by using the reflection APIs. For example, if you know that the type you are trying to read contains a property named `Name` which has a type of `string`, but you don't know the actual type you're going to be passed, you can use something like this:

```
public static string GetName(object someObject)
{
  return (string)someObject.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(someObject);
}
```

But of course, now that we have C# 4, we can also use `dynamic` to achieve the same thing easier and faster (though not safer - it's still runtime binding):

```
public static string GetName(dynamic someObject)
{
  return someObject.Name;
}
```

Obviously, `dynamic` doesn't have IntelliSense :) Also of note is that reflection allows you to read and manipulate all the internal state of an object, while `dynamic` still obeys the usual accessibility modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously can't do this

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var adresses = ex.lpAdresses;
}
```

because the compile time type of `ex` is `Exception`, not `CustomException`.

The debugger OTOH can examine the run time type of the object referenced by `ex` and display its properties. Similar to:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var cex = ex as CustomException;
    if (cex != null)
    {
        var adresses = cex.lpAdresses;
    }
}
```